# Image download - NSURLSession received Authentication Challenge

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, nsurlsession, authenticationchallenge

I'm trying to download simple image from url 
http://d1vqbpto5tbbz0.cloudfront.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/25215844/ios-logo1.png

This is simple url access through browser without any login.

I have tried with this code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeout;
NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
[[urlSession dataTaskWithURL:urlImage] resume];
```

For this only I am receiving authentication challenge.

What is the reason for it?

I have gone through stackoverflow and found these links:

- [Simple example of NSURLSession with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711816/simple-example-of-nsurlsession-with-authentication)
- [iOS/Cocoa - NSURLSession - Handling Basic HTTPS Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105322/ios-cocoa-nsurlsession-handling-basic-https-authorization)
- [NSURLSession With Basic Authentication Challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314034/nsurlsession-with-basic-authentication-challenge)

In all links, there is mentioned to enter user:password. What user name and  password, I can enter?

Comment: It could be App Transport Security issue?

Comment: I have added  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: The method `URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` is useful when you need session with authorization or for implementing certificate pinning. In 99% cases it's not necessary, you can safely remove it, because if it is implemented, it will be called.

Comment: If the url can be accessed by browser without auth, then iOS should be able to access it too. I think there is some other problem unrelated to NSURLSession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implement the `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocol method `didReceiveChallenge`.

Whenever authentication challenge occurs this method will get calls. And you have to mention it is a trusted server.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition
                             disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks the issue is most likely due to the fact that the site isn't using SSL/TSA. To handle the challenge and load the image conform to the `NSURLSessionDelegate` delegate and implement the following method.

`- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable credential))completionHandler;`

**EDIT**

Another option would be to specify arbitrary loads in your plist to allow loading of HTTP links. It's not recommended for a released app but for testing it's more then fine.

Add the following to your `plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```